# What is the probability that a single-particle bosonic quantum state is occupied?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, quantum-statistics

Unlike the Fermi-Dirac distribution function, the Bose-Einstein distribution function $$f(E)=\bar n_r=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}-1}$$ can be greater than 1, and therefore, doesn't represent a probability. It represents the average number of particles $\bar n_r$ in a single-particle quantum state $r$. What is the expression for a single-particle quantum state $r$ being occupied or unoccupied? Can we related that to $f(E)$ or $\bar n_r$?

Comment: $P(E)=Z^{-1}\exp(-\beta E)$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Is there a way the mean number of particles in a given single-particle quantum state be related to the probability of occupation of that state?

Comment: See [How to derive Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein distribution using canonical ensemble?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18576/84967).

Comment: Unoccupied: $p(n_r=0)$ and occupied: $p(n_r\neq0)=1-p(n_r=0)$, $p(n_r=0)=1/Z_r$, $Z_r=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta(E-\mu)}}$ (sum of geometric progression), so $p(n_r=0)=\frac{e^{-\beta(E-\mu)}}{\bar n_r}$ -  something like this

Comment: or of course  $p(n_r=0)=\frac{1}{1+\bar n_r}$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = e^{-\beta (E - \mu)}$. Essentially by definition, the probability $p_n$ of having occupancy number $n$
$$p_n = \frac{x^n}{Z}$$
where the probability distribution is normalized by the partition function 
$$Z = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
Then the probability that the occupancy number is zero is
$$p_0 = \frac{x^0}{Z} = 1 - x.$$
The probability that the occupancy number is nonzero is $x$. The average occupancy is
$$\langle n \rangle = \sum_n n p_n = (1-x) \sum_n n x^n = \frac{1}{x^{-1} - 1}$$
which is the result you quoted. In particular, $p_0$ and $\langle n \rangle$ are related by
$$p_0 = \frac{1}{1 + \langle n \rangle}.$$

Comment: As far as I can see the question was to express the probability through $\bar n_r$

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist You're right, I put that in.

Comment: It is interesting that in the case of fermions, the result is completely different: $p_0=1-<n>$

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist Yeah, but also, note that the two match at first order in $\langle n \rangle$, because that is the classical limit!

Comment: By the way, the variable $x$ is more suited for the case of parafermions of the order $k$: $p_0=\frac{x-1}{x^{k} - 1}$, to express the probability in terms of $<n>$ would be a problem, I guess